# Замена матрицы в ноутбуке на другую модель

Tags: железо, ноутбук

Имеется ноутбук Samsung с разбитой матрицей `LTN156AT19`. Можно заменить матрицу на другую модель? Ноутбук довольно старый и не охота отдавать от 5,5к за такую же матрицу. Существуют модели аналогичные по характеристикам, но в 2 раза дешевле, например: `LTN156AT39`, `LTN156AT30`, `LTN156AT35`

Comment: Вам лучше на http://www.cyberforum.ru/notebook-repair/ спросить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Купил и поставил б/у матрицу `LTN156AT19`

Comment: Б/у недолго прослужит, лучше бы другую модель, если совместима, но новую.

Comment: Почему так категорично не долго? Пока не разобьют опять - будет служить. А ответа по возможной установке другой модели (более дешевой) я не получил.

Comment: Нет, это вы слишком категоричны. Нельзя быть уверенным в таком точном и сложном приборе. Новый Samsung S7 взрывался, а вы уповаете на старье. Мало ли что может быть, может пластик, примененный в рамке, перед этим 3 раза на свалке был, а тут завышен срок службы - поведет его - и стеклышко ХРЯСТЬ! может светодиоды подсветки погорят... Какого еще ответа вам? Я бы просто пошел к человеку, у которого есть разные модели, с ноутбуком, и померял бы - по разъему и крепежу, и вот он ответ. И матрица новая и экономия. Но в этой стране, как обычно, ТУПОЕ жлобство...

Comment: В этой стране люди только для кидалова хорошо подходят - кидать их. Со своей жадностью и глупостью уже в откровенную халяву верят. Вот если бы была матрица, за которую обещали ВАМ доплатить - вы бы и такую взяли :)

Comment: @Rou1997, Спасибо ваше за мнение